# Upgrade MediaWiki

Tags: php, timezone, mediawiki

I am getting an error on my WIKI site that reads as this:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /home/dorotinf/public_html/wikigenia/includes/GlobalFunctions.php on line 2300.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/dorotinf/public_html/wikigenia/includes/GlobalFunctions.php on line 2300.
```

but line 2300 doesn't deal with timezone.

Got this warning, after updating the site's software, and now the site doesn't open.
Anyone know what is to be done?

Comment: Did you try to search for every occurrence of the named functions via an editor? Then you may find the correct line.

Comment: 1. "but line 2300 doesn't deal with timezone." so how it looks? 2. Warning is self explanatory - you must have set default timezone - in php.ini or via appropriate PHP function mentioned in content of this warning. 3. Another thing is that you have also syntax error. Without code we can't help it.

Comment: Is there a way to locate the syntax error? The doc is original I didn't make any change in it.

Comment: What MediaWiki version are you using, what fPHP files did you change if any, what method did you use to update MediaWiki, what's your configuration in LocalSettings.php?